# Updating Windows DNS records from a remote windows DNS server

Tags: windows-server-2003, domain-name-system, internal-dns

Does anyone know if it is possible for a windows 2003 DNS server to update the records for a domain so that it contains all the records of a domain of of a remotely based DNS server?

Im almost certain that doesn't quite explain the problem so I shall illustrate with an example:

We have two offices, both are based about 100 miles apart. One deals with IT (Intranet development etc.) while the other is a call centre that uses the Intranet systems. Currently each office has its own DNS server, with the IT office's and call centre's DNS servers containing entries for intranet site. The difference is that the IT DNS server records point to the various servers that host the Intranet sites (e.g. intranetsite1 -> 192.168.1.10, intranetsite2 -> 192.168.1.11) while all of the entries in the call centre's DNS point to the IT office's DNS server (intranetsite1 -> [it office ip address], intranetsite2 -> [it office ip address]).

Is there any way that the call centre's DNS server could automatically add all DNS records hosted by the IT office's DNS, translating the IP addresses to the IP address of the IT office?

Answer (score 1):

Setup the call centre server as a [secondary server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc776953(WS.10).aspx) for the IT zone.